# Database design to support multiple clients

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

If you were building a database with tables Documents, Clients, Users and Firms, where in Firms you would store the companies that use the software how would you design the first three tables to support multiple Firms to store in them? So, in Documents we want to store documents for all the firms, of course, we need to tell them appart somehow, so we would need a column like FirmID. We can also put this in Clients and Users.

Now the next requirement is that each firm can have its own IDs for documents, clients, because obviosuly when we add a new firm, their IDs for whatever they create should start at 1.

I was thinking something like this but it requires manual construction of all the fields but RowID.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientTest](
 [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FirmID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ClientFirmID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ClientFirmPrettyID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [RowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

RowID will run automatically in this case but it's useless for us because for everything we do we need to use ClientFirmID and ClientFirmPrettyID. Is there a way to automate the creation of these two ?

Comment: I have added other solution to my answer

Comment: I have added image and some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to use database facade pattern (views, stored procedures). They hide all database internals (structure) from other world. I think, it is another point that is security. Every firm wants to have restricted access to some data on table level, (not row level). The second point is: performance. It is better have many tables than one big one.

So I think, it is better to leave tables of every firm as they are and create a view for reports (I think):

```
CREATE view dbo.Client
    as
    SELECT  ClientId= ClientId, FirmPrettyId = 'first'
    FROM         dbo.FirstCompanyClient 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT     ClientId = Client_Id, FirmPrettyId = 'second'
    FROM                       dbo.SecondCompanyClient
```

or

**ADDED:**

[image]

Use trigger or stored procedure to generate the next id for some firm and scope ('clients' or 'documents'):

```
UPDATE dbo.zz_IdGenerator 
    SET
        @nextId = NextId,
        NextId = @nextId + 1
    WHERE FirmId = @firmId and Scope = @scope 

    RETURN  @nextId;
```

**UPDATED:**

Insert `UPDATE dbo.zz_IdGenerator...`  into stored procedure, and call it before insert to the document or client tables.

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is a bit more understandable. Now I see you are basing your sample on two tables. However, I do not want two tables despite all the reasons there might exist for that.

Comment: Hello, what do you think about sharing the same clients between two (or) more firms?

Comment: I am setting up a test DB based on this answer. Where do I attach this code?

Comment: About the sharing - your design implicates sharing because you've set up many to many relationship by making the middle two additional tables. It doesn't mean that if all the clients are in the same table, they will be available to everyone. If we move FirmID FK to the Clients table, we have one to many relationship between Firms and Clients. We don't need many to many because if we have the same Client for multiple firms it will be added multiple times. If we have a client named ABC Company, we don't want our different firms stored in Firms table to all use the same row.

Comment: Firm 1 adds client named ABC Company. Entry in Clients table will be a new row with FirmId FK set to Firm 1's ID. Firm 2 adds a client named ABC Company (let's assume that it is exactly the same business company/entity). Firm 2 doesn't need to know, in fact, it shouldn't know, that there is already that business entity in the Clients table. For Firm 2 it doesn't exist. So it is being added once again and it has nothing to do with the client ABC Company that Firm 1 added. Given that information and requirements we can safely assume that many-many relationship is not needed.

Comment: So we could easily ditch the many-many tables and leave only Clients, Firms and Generator table (and Documents but that's essential the same as Clients, just a different type of content). If you correct your answer to include this new information I provided, I will accept your answer (since you contributed the most to this thread).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, an opinion

- Would recommend that you keep a unique surrogate PK on all tables for uniquess of join (i.e. Keep your RowID's)
- As you've suggested with your "PrettyId", the firm-unique "Sequence" of Document, Client etc for each firm won't be the PK. You'll need a separate counters pattern or similar for this. You can also enforce a Unique Constraint on (*PrettyId, FirmId) on each table.
- Although not 4NF form, it might be a good idea for Security and Sanity purposes to Stamp a FirmId Foreign Key on *ALL* your Firm Specific tables (Rationale : Just about every query issued by your system will probably want to filter by FirmId). This would also give performance benefits since you won't necessarily need to join back to the first neighbours of Firm in order to do this filtering (and FirmId FK will need to go into all indexes.

HTH

Comment: This is a reasonable answer. I will keep the autoincrement PKs on all tables and probably set FirmID column as FK on all also. What I would like to learn more about is those sequences or sequence generators.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a primary key is to uniquely identify a row in a table, not to serve as some kind of a business key which may have some meaning.

If you need custom numbering sequence for each customer, a column (`DocumentCustomId`) can be added for that.

In Oracle, DB2, Postgresql  a sequence object can be used -- in SQL server you have to create a custom sequencer, hence the `DocumentSequence` table. The access to the table should be through a stored procedure(s) which should implement

- create_sequence
- next_vale
- current_value
- previous_value

When inserting a new document, the `DocumentId` auto-increments, while the `DocumentCustomId` should be obtained as a `next_value` from the sequencer object.

[image: doc_model_v3]

Here are few links to sequence objects in **[DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_sql_createsequence.htm)**, **[Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm)**, **[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createsequence.html)** to help with the concept.

Comment: I think this is almost understandable but do you have any samples for sequencing on SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup PK - FK relationship appropriately to handle the table data. For example if an Firm has multiple docs (obviously a firm can), then in the Table of DOcuments you can have a FirmID as fk, which is PK of Firm Table. Or the best to learn relationship is mapping. Do one thing, create the required tables independenlty  without any relationship between the tables. Say you have 4 then create 4 tables,that will be Users, Documents, Firms, and Clients. Now create one more table that will handle the relationship of any two table. For example. 
Doc and Firm.

Craete a new table DocFirmMapTable with three columns DocFirmMapId as its PK, DocId, FirmId. Just you need to take care of that while inserting into the two tables you need to make a one more insert in their respective map tables. Also in map table you can keep mapping of two or more than two tables as per you requirement.

Comment: This is not a question about one-many or many-many relationship. I know those. This is about special sequence columns besides the normal ID autoincrement column.